# How to evaluate this limit??

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, riemann-sum

> Evaluate: $$\ f(x)= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( \dfrac{n^n(x+n)\left( x+\dfrac{n}{2}\right)\left( x+\dfrac{n}{3}\right)... \left( x+\dfrac{n}{n}\right)}{n!(x^2+n^2)\left( x^2+\dfrac{n^2}{4}\right)\left( x^2+\dfrac{n^2}{9}\right)...\left( x^2+\dfrac{n^2}{n^2}\right)}\right)^{\dfrac{x}{n}}$$

$x\in R^+$
Find the coordinates of the maxima of $f(x)$.

Comment: Yep, better title.

Comment: Best is to typeset the formulas using LaTeX (at least the parts where you are unsure), as all respondent do, but showing clean drafts is fine, provided you show them in portrait layout.

Comment: Do. Not. Deface the question by replacing with another one. That is rude to the users who kindly answered your question.

Comment: Do. Not. Repost a question either. These are site rules, and I have been elected by popular vote to enforce such rules - a kind of a human exception handler.

Comment: @amWhy thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We solve it using Riemann sum. You can write it as $$\left(\frac {(\frac {x}{n}+1)\cdots (\frac {nx}{n}+1)}{((\frac{x}{n})^2+1)\cdots ((\frac {nx}{n})^2+1)}\right)^{x/n}$$

Now take logs and use the fact of Riemann sum. Put $\dfrac {1}{n}=\mathrm dt,\dfrac {r}{n}=t$ in numerator and denominator where $r$ varies from $1-n $ thus the limit changes to integration. The equation becomes $\displaystyle \ln f (x))=x\int _0 ^1\ln \left(\frac {xt+1}{x^2t^2+1}\right)\mathrm dt $

Note we are integrating wrt $t $ so treat $x$ as constant. Put $xt=p $ thus $x\, \mathrm dt=\mathrm dp $ . Now limits change from $0$ to $x$ so we have $\displaystyle \ln (f (x))=\int _0 ^x \ln \left(\frac {1+p}{1+p^2}\right)\, \mathrm dp. $ Now use log property to separate the integral and then by parts . So we get $\displaystyle \ln (f (x))=(x+1)(\ln (x+1)-1)-\int _0 ^1 \frac {2p^2+2-2 }{1+p^2}\, \mathrm dp $ thus the result is $\ln (f (x))=(x+1)(\ln (x+1)-1)+1-x\ln (1+x^2)+2x-2\arctan (x)$ .

Now you can see that $f'(x)=\ln (1+x)-\ln (1+x^2) $ thus maxima is achived either at $0$ or $1$ . Using second derivative test we see the maxima is at $1$ thus putting $x=1$ we have $f (1)=e^{\ln (2)+1-\frac {\pi}{2}}=2.e.e^{-pi/2}=2ei^i\approx 1.12$ thus coordinates are $(1,1.13)$.